# Ubuntu freezes while FF or Chromium are running

Tags: firefox, chromium, freeze, 17.04

Following a regular software update my Ubuntu installation became unstable. The problem first manifested on 16.04. Each time I opened Firefox 53.0, the whole system froze within a minute of browsing. Traditional keyboard shortcuts were unable to unfreeze it. Reinstalling FF didn't help. Switching to Chromium didn't help - the problem persisted in exactly the same form, only in Chromium. Upgrading to 16.10 didn't help. Upgrading to 17.04 changed the nature of the problem slightly - now, FF freezes and unfreezes very frequently, every couple of minutes. I do not experience problems running applications other than FF and Chromium. Do you have any suggestions what further steps I might take to fix this?

Comment: Is your HDD busy while the freeze happens? Can you move the mouse cursor or use keyboard during the freeze?

Comment: I am on SSD, HDD is dormant. I am able to move the cursor around and use the keyboard. Additionally, hitting Ctrl + Alt + F1 switches to the full-screen terminal which prompts me for a login but not for a pass.