# Ubuntu 17.10 frequent freezes

Tags: firefox, freeze, 17.10

After upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10 Ubuntu freezes frequently in 2 specific situations:

1) On loading a new page/tab in Firefox. Sometimes, the system unfreezes after a while. Sometimes not.

2) On shutdown. More often than not, it doesn't unfreeze from this state.

This is different from several similar questions I have found here in that it doesn't matter what display server I use. Wayland, XORG and Unity display the same behavior.
It might also be of importance that I used to experience similar (but not exactly the same) problems after upgrading from 16.04. Details:

[Ubuntu freezes while FF or Chromium are running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909471/ubuntu-freezes-while-ff-or-chromium-are-running)

In the previous case, the freezes tapered off in time. This doesn't seem to be the case now. Any suggestions of what might be causing the problem or what diagnostic tools I might use would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Erasing and reinstalling Ubuntu seems to have helped.

**EDIT 2**

I might have located the culprit. The problem came back right after I installed Sophos Antivirus. Uninstalling the app seems to have solved it.

Comment: Tools: (read `man` on each): `free`, `swapon --show`, `uptime`, `top`, and I'm sure others may suggest more.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have problems like this whenever I upgraded my Ubuntu installation. The truth is an upgrade will never match a fresh installation at least not in my experience.To solve this problem I use advanced partitioning when installing Ubuntu. Home directory onto a separate partition you can follow the guides https://www.tecmint.com/move-home-directory-to-new-partition-disk-in-linux/ and [Move home folder to second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive). This allows me to do a fresh installation whenever I want with minimum interuptions